# Counting rows in dataframe in python that match the condition which refers to varying value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create in my dataframe `BoughtProducts` a column `CustomerPurchases` which would contain the number of previous purchases of the customer. The dataframe contains among others the order date (`OrderDateTime`) and customer number (`CustomerNumber`) and I would like to count for each row, how many rows with the same customer number and earlier order dates are there in the dataframe. I tried to do it like that:

```py
for index, row in BoughtProducts.iterrows():

  row['CustomersPurchases']=BoughtProducts[(BoughtProducts['OrderDateTime']<=row['OrderDateTime'])&(BoughtProducts['CustomerNumber']==row['CustomerNumber'])].count()
```

But it takes ages to run the loop and I believe there is an easier and faster way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `sort_values`, `groupby` and the `cumcount` function.

```
BoughtProducts['CustomersPurchases'] = (
    BoughtProducts
    .sort_values(by['OrderDateTime']))
    .groupby('CustomerNumber')
    .cumcount()+1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, this solution is great for the problem that I presented in the question. And what if I need to count how many times the customer has occurred before the date in a different dataframe that also has a OrderDateTime and CustomerNumber attribute (let's call it ReturnedProducts), meaning that for each row in the table BoughtProducts I would need to count how many rows in the table ReturnedProducts have the same CustomerNumber and earlier OrderDateTime?

Comment: @Maja If my answer did provide a way to do what you wanted, feel free to mark my question as the accepted answer. I will not provide a complete solution, but I think you could use what I have written above. 1. Create a columns in each df to mark type. Add the dataframes together using pandas.concat. Create new columns that are 1/0 depending on if it is BoughtProducts, ReturnedProducts. Do same as above, but change cumcount to cumsum.